# What is the correct encoding of BOSCH in NYSIIS?

Tags: java, r, nlp, matching

What is the correct encoding of BOSCH in NYSIIS?  I am building an indexing system which needs to be robust against slight differences in spelling of names.

Testing the method in R, produces "BAS": 
`require(phonics); nysiis('BOSCH')`

The java code https://rosettacode.org/wiki/NYSIIS#Java produces "BA".

While the commons library org.apache.commons.codec.language.Nysiis class produces "B".

The "BAS" looks most correct to me as suggested by the website http://www.dropby.com/NYSIIS.html

Here are the rules as published at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Nysiis.html

Algorithm description:

```
 1. Transcode first characters of name
   1a. MAC ->   MCC
   1b. KN  ->   NN
   1c. K   ->   C
   1d. PH  ->   FF
   1e. PF  ->   FF
   1f. SCH ->   SSS
 2. Transcode last characters of name
   2a. EE, IE          ->   Y
   2b. DT,RT,RD,NT,ND  ->   D
 3. First character of key = first character of name
 4. Transcode remaining characters by following these rules, incrementing by one character each time
   4a. EV  ->   AF  else A,E,I,O,U -> A
   4b. Q   ->   G
   4c. Z   ->   S
   4d. M   ->   N
   4e. KN  ->   N   else K -> C
   4f. SCH ->   SSS
   4g. PH  ->   FF
   4h. H   ->   If previous or next is nonvowel, previous
   4i. W   ->   If previous is vowel, previous
   4j. Add current to key if current != last key character
 5. If last character is S, remove it
 6. If last characters are AY, replace with Y
 7. If last character is A, remove it
 8. Collapse all strings of repeated characters
 9. Add original first character of name as first character of key
```

Comment: A useful blog: http://ntz-develop.blogspot.com/2011/03/phonetic-algorithms.html

Answer (score 1):

Based solely upon that algorithm description, the answer is "BAS".

Comment: Yes that was my assessment as well. I think the apache commons code misinterprets rule 5 as removing all trailing 'S's which then triggers rule 7.  Rule 8 as you agree is the real rule to evoke in the case of BOSCH->BASCH->BASSS->BASS->BAS